# C# convert Datatable to class

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a Datatable to a c# class.

I am using the following method to convert
this i developed as a console application. I have not referenced  entity framework on console application.

```
**Class1**  items = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
   new Class1
   {
       id = row.Field<string>("id"),
       name = row.Field<string>("name")
   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

when i implied this code to my real time project

I am getting the following error

**The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.**

I do not want to refer entity frame work and in my console application i have not referenced any thing.It is working perfectly. why i am getting this error in my real time project

Is there any other way to convert datatable to c# class.

My application is in c# ,visual studio 2008 console application.

error is showing in Class1
Console and real time project are in vs 2008

Comment: What is your real time project? WinForms? Console? Web application?

Comment: What line does the error appear for?

Comment: @Shadow, c# console vs 2008 error in Line Class1

Comment: Both projects point to the same .NET framework version?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Console and real time project are in vs 2008

Comment: Entity Framework and Datasets are two different layers of ADO.NET. From the code you have shown us in your example, you would only need to have System.Data.dll referenced with the System.Data namespace imported.

Comment: @Despertar from quick look I think the required assembly is [System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348900.aspx)

Comment: Where does the datatable come from? It is more likely that the exception occurs there. BTW There is quite some discrepancy between the title + tag and the actual question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yea I thought so too, but I wonder why the error the OP says shows, I checked if DataSetExtensions has dependencies on `Data.Entity` and it doesn't

Comment: What DLLs are you currently referencing in the project?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your referencing issue sorted out, and assuming you do actually want to convert from rows in a DataTable to instances of a .NET class, take a look at [this blog post](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2006/01/15/284.aspx).

Lets you do this:

```
// create and fill table
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(new object[]{1});
table.Rows.Add(new object[]{2});
table.Rows.Add(new object[]{3});

// create a wrapper around Rows
LinqList<DataRow> rows = new LinqList<DataRow>(table.Rows);

// do a simple select
IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows = from r in rows
       where (int)r["Id"] == 2
       select r;

// output result
foreach (DataRow row in selectedRows)
  Console.WriteLine(row["Id"]);
```

Comment: Why not just dt.AsEnumerable()? The data set extensions do just that.

Comment: Oh. Didn't know that! Neat! Although, OP does say: "I do not want to refer entity frame work" - are the dataset extensions in EF?

Comment: Nah, they're in System.Data.DataSetExtensions. Super handy.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this as a quick test - literally just add new console app and the below code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "test" });

        var item = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
           new  {
               id = row.Field<string>("id"),
               name = row.Field<string>("name")
           }).First();

        Console.WriteLine(item.name);
    }
```

I'm only referencing `System.Data` and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` (well.. and `System`/`System.Core`/`Microsoft.CSharp`/`System.Xml`/`System.Xml.Linq`). The problem isn't with the code you posted, it lies somewhere that we can't see. Can you post the full list of DLLs that you are referencing.

You definitely do not require a reference to `System.Data.Entity.dll` to do what you're doing. Search through all your source files for `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses` to see where you are referencing a class in the Entity Framework library. It might also be pulled in from a library you are referencing.